# Verilog specify block within for-loop

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to model path delays for an n-bit wide signal. I can do this fine if I explicitly define the delay for each individual bit, like this (n=3):

```
specify
    (in_data[0] => delayed_data[0]) = 5;
    (in_data[1] => delayed_data[1]) = 2;
    (in_data[2] => delayed_data[2]) = 1;
endspecify
```

However, I want to be able to specify random delays for each bit of `in_data` when `in_data` is n-bits wide. My idea was something like this:

```
for (n=0;n<DATA_WIDTH-1;n=n+1)
begin
    specify
       (in_data[n] => delayed_data[n]) = {$random};
    endspecify
end
```

This gives me an error:

> near 'specify': syntax error, unexpected specify

I also tried placing the `for` loop within the `specify` block.  This resulted in the following error:

> near 'begin': syntax error, unexpected begin, expecting endspecify

I would really appreciate any tips on how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Doulos Verilog Reference Guide](http://www.fpga.com.cn/hdl/training/verilog%20reference%20guide.pdf) (page 84) a specify block can only occur within `module` and `endmodule` tags, and not within anything else.

According to [this Verilog reference website](http://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00044.htm):

> The Specify block was designed to define a delay across a module. It starts with specify and ends with the endspecify keyword. Inside the block the user can specify: specparam declaration, path declaration or system timing check.

This seems to imply it does not allow for-loops within specify blocks.

Hence it leads me to believe that you'll need to write out all the values one by one due to a limitation of the language.

---

One idea you could try is to restructure your modules to have a one bit input to a one bit output. Then each specify block will only have one delay to specify, and you can assign them each a random value. You can then generate these modules inside a `generate` block which will avoid you having to specify a delay for each bit manually.

*However,* this may be more tedious/awkward.